# How to display images in rows and columns?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am querying some images from database and displaying them on the webpage. However, I would like to display these images in rows and columns as thumbnails.

For example:

If c1, c2, c3, c4 and c5 are 5 columns and r1, r2, and r3 are 3 rows, then the page should show 15 image thumbnails.

I'm using bootstrap.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Nothing. I have no idea how to begin.

Comment: Ok, this may be a good place to start http://www.google.com/

Comment: Yeah. Searched but Couldn't find anything specific to question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the basic grid system and `thumbnail` classes to create the structure you want.

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/120x150" /></a>
      </div>
      ...
</div>
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/120x150" /></a>
      </div>
      ...
</div>
...
```

[**Here's a JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ujLbU/) to demonstrate. You can pick your grid classes based on the layout you want to achieve. The Bootstrap documentation for the [grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) will help you loads.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is about it

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="hidden-phone">
      </div>
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12 well">

        <div class="row-fluid">
          <ul class="thumbnails">

            <li class="span4">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/320x200" alt="ALT NAME">
                <div class="caption">
                  <h3>Title</h3>


                  <p align="center">
                    <a href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-toggle="modal">View Image</a>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li> 
             <li class="span4">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/320x200" alt="ALT NAME">
                <div class="caption">
                  <h3>Title</h3>

                  <p align="center">
                    <a href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-toggle="modal">View Image</a>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li> 
             <li class="span4">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/320x200" alt="ALT NAME">
                <div class="caption">
                  <h3>Title</h3>
                  <p align="center">
                    <a href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-toggle="modal">View Image</a>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li> 
          </ul>
        </div>
          <div class="row-fluid">
          <ul class="thumbnails">

            <li class="span4">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/320x200" alt="ALT NAME">
                <div class="caption">
                  <h3>Title</h3>
                  <p align="center">
                    <a href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-toggle="modal">View Image</a>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li> 
             <li class="span4">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/320x200" alt="ALT NAME">
                <div class="caption">
                  <h3>Title</h3>
                  <p align="center">
                    <a href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-toggle="modal">View Image</a>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li> 
             <li class="span4">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/320x200" alt="ALT NAME">
                <div class="caption">
                  <h3>Title</h3>
                  <p align="center">
                    <a href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-toggle="modal">View Image</a>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
ul.thumbnails li.span4:nth-child(3n + 4) {
  margin-left : 0px;
}
```

**Fiddle:** [**http://jsfiddle.net/Z3VwZ/11/**](http://jsfiddle.net/Z3VwZ/12/)